# VB to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, insert, textbox

I'm trying to insert new data into an SQL server from what user had input in a textbox.
My code is not functioning, please help me.

```
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LANDSLIDE\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=PayrollSQL;User ID=sa;Password=lismyadmin"

    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Member ([Name], [Code], [NRIC]) VALUES(" & TextBox1.Text & "," & TextBox2.Text & "," & TextBox3.Text & ")"
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to use parameterised queries. Something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Member ([Name], [Code], [NRIC]) VALUES(@Name,@Code,@NRIC)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code",TextBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC",TextBox3.Text)
```

At the moment, you're ending up with your strings appearing literally in your SQL statement - and whatever values you're retrieving from `TextBox1`-`3` aren't valid pieces of SQL (hopefully - if they are actually valid SQL, you're performing SQL injection)

(By the way, you're allowed to rename controls - you ought to rename those `TextBox`es so that you don't have to remember that, say, `TextBox2` is the one for code)

Answer (score 2):

May be it will work or else provide error message:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Member ([Name], [Code], [NRIC]) VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "')"
```

Comment: Of course, this wouldn't cope if the text boxes might contain `'` characters, and is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes you are right, i was just trying to solve one's problem by providing him the clue. Not the best way of doing it.